# "Taylor series" in the context of partitions of a number

Tags: abstract-algebra, integer-partitions

Aluffi IV.4.4 (on the symmetric group) suggests the following exercise:

> Make sense of the 'Taylor series' of the infinite product
>   $$
> \frac{1}{1 - x} \cdot \frac{1}{1 - x^2} \cdot \frac{1}{1 - x^3} \cdot \frac{1}{1 - x^4} \cdot \frac{1}{1 - x^5} \cdot \cdots.
> $$
>   Prove that the coefficient of $x^n$ in this series is the number of partitions of $n$.

So let's start with the first few examples:

- $x$ is contributed by $\frac{1}{1 - x}$ — that's not particularly enlightening, so let's keep going.
- $x^2$ — by $\frac{1}{1 - x}$ and $\frac{1}{1 - x^2}$.
- $x^3$ — by $\frac{1}{1 - x}$, $\frac{1}{1 - x^3}$ and $\frac{1}{1 - x} \cdot \frac{1}{1 - x^2}$ (as $x \cdot x^2$).
- $x^4$ — by $\frac{1}{1 - x}$, $\frac{1}{1 - x^2}$, $\frac{1}{1 - x^4}$, $\frac{1}{1 - x} \cdot \frac{1}{1 - x^2}$ (as $x^2 \cdot x^2$) and $\frac{1}{1 - x} \cdot \frac{1}{1 - x^3}$ (as $x \cdot x^3$).

At this point I'm staring at these expressions and trying to come up with a rule to match them with how I'd partition the corresponding naturals, but I'm not sure if I can *make sense* out of it. So how do I do that?

Comment: Use the fact that $\sum x^k = \frac{1}{1-x}$

Comment: I'm not sure I can find a better use for it than just the literal expansion of the Taylor series.

Comment: If $\sum x^k = \frac{1}{1-x}$, and $\sum x^{2k} = \frac{1}{1-x^2}$, so on and so forth, then your inline expression is equal to $(1 + x + x^2 + \dots)(1 + x^2 + x^4 + \dots)(1 + x^3 + x^6 + x^9 \dots)(1+ x^4 + x^8 + \dots)\cdots$

Comment: Look at that and think about how many copies of $x^4$ you will get during the expansion. You will get one when you do $x^2 \cdot x^2 = x^{2+2}$, one when you do $x \cdot x \cdot x^2 = x^{1 + 1 + 2}$, etc. In particular, there will be a copy of $x^n$ for each partition, $P(n)$. If you still arent convinced expand the following out by hand and don't simplify exponents (leave them as a sum so you can see the partitions): $(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)(1+x^2+x^4)(1+x^3)(1+x^4)$.

Comment: That's roughly how I obtained the examples in my question. But how will you get $x \cdot x \cdot x^2$ in particular? There's only one $x^1$ (in the first factor). Or, for example, I got three different $x^4$ (from the first, second and fourth factor), and I'm not sure how to interpret that.

Comment: The product of the first two is: $1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^2+x^{1+2}+x^{2+2}+x^{3+2}+x^{4+2}+x^{4}+x^{1+4}+x^{2+4}+x^{3+4}+x^{4+4}$ The product of the second two is $1+x^4+x^3+x^{3+4}$. In computing the final product, we can drop anything that has an exponent higher than 4, since were just looking for $P(4)$. So we have $(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^2+x^{1+2}+x^{2+2}+x^4)(1+x^3+x^4)$

Comment: Yep! Note there's already a pair of different $x^4$'s!

Comment: Expanding the last line, again ignoring exponents bigger than 4, we have $1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^2+x^{1+2}+x^{2+2}+x^4+x^3+x^{3+1}+x^4$. Joining like terms, that is $1+x+2x^2+3x^3+5x^4$ which the coefficients are indeed the first 4 partition numbers

Comment: Identify each term that comes out of the product $(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)(1+x^2+x^4)(1+x^3)(1+x^4)$, which will be of the form $x^k = x^{a_1} \cdot x^{a_2} \cdot x^{a_3} \cdot x^{a_4},$ with the 4-tuple $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4)$. This will correspond to a partition in the following way: $a_1$ is the number of 1's, $a_2/2$ is the number of 2's, $a_3/3$ is the number of 3's, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ \prod_{j=1}^k \frac{1}{1-x^j} =\prod_{j=1}^k \left(\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} x^{jm}\right)=\left(\sum_{m_{\large1}=0}^{\infty} x^{1m_{\large1}}\right)\left(\sum_{m_{\large2}=0}^\infty x^{2m_{\large 2}}\right)\cdots\left(\sum_{m_k=0}^{\infty} x^{km_k}\right) $$

$$ = \sum_{m_{\large1}=0}^{\infty} \sum_{m_{\large 2}=0}^{\infty} \cdots \sum_{m_k=0}^{\infty} x^{1m_{\large 1}+2m_{\large 2}+\cdots+km_k}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} p_k(n)x^n $$

Here, the number of times $x^n$ appears is the number of nonnegative integer solutions $(m_1,m_2,\cdots,m_k)$ to the equation $1m_1+2m_2+\cdots+km_k=n$. These tuples, in turn, correspond to partitions of $n$ into parts of size $\le k$; the component $m_j$ is simply the multiplicity of $j$ in such a partition! As an integer partition is unordered, to specify a partition all we really need to do is specify the multiplicity of each integer $1,2,\cdots$ as we do with $(m_1,\cdots,m_k)$.

When $k>n$, the term $p_k(n)$ is constant as $k$ is increased further, namely it is $p(n)$. So as $k\to\infty$,

$$ \prod_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1-x^j}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} p(n)x^n. $$

I'm ignoring issues of convergence as analytic functions. (However if we interpret them as "formal power series" there is an implicit "$(x)$-adic" topology in which this clearly converges. Fun trick.)